# Two websites, same url, same cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, web

We are thinking about rewriting a web application. The old application is written in Java and the new one in c#. I want to rewrite it incrementally. So let's say this web application has 10 screens:

First rewrite screen 1, deploy it. Use only 9 screens from the old web application, and 1 screen from the new web application.
NExt rewrite screen 2, deploy it. Use only 8 screens from the old web application, and 2 screens from the new web application.

For this to work both applications probably must run on the same url and reuse the cookie.

IS this even possible?

Comment: Yes. Put proxy in front and split traffic by URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sub.domain, each in different platform

You can use cookie by domain for share cookie.
Set the same domain or subdomain in Java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setDomain%28java.lang.String%29

And in C#:

Response.Cookies("domain").Domain = "support.contoso.com"

Related question :
[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain#23086139)